# printing out 2d array from files

Tags: c++

How do i print out this text file in form of a 2D array to the console window.

[maze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82MU3.png)

I wrote this code but it seems to disregard the spaces as characters.

```
ifstream mazefile("maze.txt");

char maz[21][31] = {};

int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < 21; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 31; j++)
    {
        mazefile >> maz[i][j];
        cout << maz[i][j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `std::istream::operator<<()` skips all whitespaces (spaces, tabs, newlines). Since you need the whitespaces, you should consider using `istream::get()` or `istream::getline()`.

Pick one of below to start with, note you may need to manually handle the newline with `get`.

```
mazfile.get(maz[i][j]);
mazfile.get();  // Trailing newline

mazfile.get(maz[i], 30);
mazfile.get();  // Trailing newline

mazfile.get(maz[i], 30, '\n');  // With newline as delimiter
mazfile.get();  // Trailing newline

mazfile.getline(maz[i]);
```

Alternatively, you can force whitespace to be **not** skipped:

```
mazfile >> noskipws >> maz[i][j];
```